Why does the percentage height of internal elements inherit the height of non direct ancestor elements?
Why does the percentage height of inner elements inherit the height of the ancestor element with the most recently set height when the height of the parent element is not set？
In my understanding, isn't the percentage height only inherited from the explicitly set parent element height? When the parent element does not set a height, it degenerates into auto and relies on its content to infer the height.
In the following example, D should only have text height, but it inherits the height of A. Chrome and Firefox both exhibit this behavior.
Is there a problem with my understanding？


<html>
<body>
<div id="A"  style="height: 500px;">
  <div id="B" style="height: 10px;"></div>
  <div id="C" >
    <div id="D" style="height: 100%;">123</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>




did you declare the doctype on the top of your html page?

@TemaniAfif You're right, when I declared the doctype(add  to start of document), CSS behavior met my expectations.Why is this?
